# Compiling project as Java 1.3 vs. 1.8 - any downside?

Tags: java

We have a large (old) Java servlet project that is still compiled for Java 1.3, we run this code only in our own server with a modern JRE.

What is the downside of compiling classes for 1.3 instead of targeting to latest modern 1.8?
 Are there any risks, if we start to compile code for 1.8?

Comment: I don't see any downside as such.  If you are worried only about compilation, most features are backward compatible, so you should be fine.

Comment: Where are you planning to run these binaries? What's your target environment?

Comment: You say you're compiling for Java 1.3, but what version of the JVM are you running on? (I really hope it's not the one released with 1.3.)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would think that running on a previous version would allow for security vulnerabilities.  If you want to ensure a certain level of security then you should compile to be compatible with _only_ the level of security (via the JRE version) that you are comfortable with.  Specifically, you should _not_ allow your application to be run on previous JRE versions that have known security vulnerabilities even though your code may be compatible with such lower JREs.

Comment: You should definitely have a plan to upgrade the application to compile/run on a newer version (Assuming you want to continue using it for the foreseeable future). However, you should fully test the application after doing so as you can't guarantee a subtle change won't cause an issue in your app.

Answer (score 6):

The more important question is which JRE version you are going to use to run your old code.

Using a newer version (even it the code only uses syntax and classes of the old version) has the benefit of taking advantage of all the bug fixes and performance improvements that the newer version should have.

As for using the older or newer compiler, I think it makes sense to assume the newer compiler would produce more efficient byte code, so I'd use the newer compiler even if the code remains unchanged.

Comment: The OP is asking about compilation.  There is no assumption made (as far as I can tell) as to what JRE the end user would use other than that the JRE must be at least at the level of the compiled code.  By specifying a minimal compilation target, you are specifying that you accept that (lowest) version of the JRE.

Comment: we only run this code in our own server, modern jre

Comment: @Jared Yes, I know. I originally thought the compiler version wouldn't make a difference, but I changed my mind.

Comment: @Tom If you're not changing JRE versions, then you should be able to target Java 8 bytecode with no change in behavior (except possibly some warnings about all the now-deprecated classes you're using). A JRE change, of course, is a whole other situation. As always, when making such a sweeping change, test *everything* no matter what you read online.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, the difference should be small, if any. The only bytecode op that has been added since 1.3 is invokedynamic, which 1.3 code won't use anyway. Optimization normally takes place in the JIT compiler, rather than in the byte code compiler, so it's unlikely that any changes there will improve performance.

However, if you're rebuilding it every now and then, I assume you're still doing at least some maintenance work on the code. It might be a good idea to move forward to a new version  preemptively, since older source levels eventually may become deprecated with future JDKs. The only things I can think of that can break are variables using names which have since become reserved words (`enum` for example), but once it compiles it should work fine.

Long story short, I'd recommend you to test bumping the source level and see what happens. Odds are it'll work just fine.